# What is the significance of declaring another function within a function with regards to closures in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm still struggling to wrap my mind around closures in JavaScript (for the record, I've read the answer to JavaScript closures here on Stack Overflow, plus the "JavaScript Closures for Dummies" and am still puzzled by them).

My main issue is that I'm having trouble understanding the significance of declaring another function within a function; I get that returning the inner function allows the local variables of the outer function to remain active, but isn't that still the case in this example?

```
function sayName(name) {
var say = "Hello, " + name;
alert(say);
}

var sayJohn = sayName("John");
```

The local variable, "say" is still being referenced outside of its local scope in the sayJohn() function that I've created. 
So isn't this still creating a closure?

N.B I apologize for how garbled this all sounds, still very fresh to learning JavaScript and programming in general, so please go easy on me!

Comment: sayJohn is not a function. Hence the question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Your example indeed cannot show the power of closure.
Look at this instead:

```
function makeAdder(add1){
    return function(add2){
       return add1 + add2;
    };
}

// add10 is a function which increments the input by 10(that's the closure's magic)
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

add10(12); // returns 22
add10(9); // returns 19
```

Comment: +1 great example of a factory method, though closures can be used to simply persist a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

While @HuiZheng's answer is correct, here's a simpler use case for closures:

```
var getUniqueID = (function () {
    var counter = 0;

    return function () {
        return counter++;
    };
}());

getUniqueID(); // 0
getUniqueID(); // 1
getUniqueID(); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

say is not being referenced outside sayName function. "alert" is being called from inside sayName function and hence still in the scope of sayName.

closure is a function reference which keeps the outer function variables still active even after the outer function has been removed from the call-stack